# Relationship between Frequency response, magnitude spectrum and gain

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency-response, speech-processing

I have been reading quite a lot of DSP related materials online and offline (books etc.) lately. I come across the terms **`frequency response`** and **`gain`**. I have also noticed that both are expressed in **`dB`**.

I do understand the fact that expressing the magnitude spectrum in **`dB`** is more informative and intuitive and helps identify the presence of different frequencies. But as seen [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/_images/scipy-signal-hanning-1_01.png) (or [here](http://blog.shure.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Frequency-Response-Chart.png)) and [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Avraham_Gover/publication/228999588/figure/fig2/AS:707285919744002@1545641512295/Gain-frequency-response.png), the plots basically have the same/identical parameters on X-axis as well as Y-axis i.e, its dB vs frequency. This makes me a bit confused.

What is the relationship between **`frequency response`** and **`gain`**. Are they the same thing? Are they used according to the context (in that case on what occasions it is apt to use either of them?)?

Comment: I think it's an okay question (wouldn't suggest closing the question), but, *networks_hermit*, this is about very fundamental concepts and language regarding **Linear System Theory**, sometimes called [Signals and Systems](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-011-introduction-to-communication-control-and-signal-processing-spring-2010/readings/MIT6_011S10_chap02.pdf), that is a rung down on the Electrical Engineering curriculum. So consider inputting to a linear system a sinusoidal waveform...

Answer (score 2):

ok let me give you a practical (discrete-time) example.

Consider a system with input-output relation of the form
$$ y[n] = x[n] + 0.5  x[n-1] + 0.25 x[n-2] $$

This input-output relation satisfies linearity and time-invariance properties and hence defines an LTI (linear time invariant) system and therefore it has an impulse response $h[n]$ found to be : 
$$h[n] = \delta[n] + 0.5 \delta[n-1] + 0.25 \delta[n-2] $$

Which signifies an FIR (finite impulse response) filter. Now since the system has an impulse response, then taking its Fourier transform will give us the system's so called complex valued *Frequency Response* function, denoted as $H(\omega)$ :

$$H(\omega) = \sum_n h[n] e^{-j \omega n} $$

For the above system, the frequency response can be shown to be:

$$ H(\omega) = 1 + 0.5 e^{-j \omega} + 0.25 e^{-j2\omega} $$

The magnitude of $H(\omega)$ signifies the (linear) **gain** that the LTI system applies to its input at the frequency $\omega$. For example, if $ |H(\omega)| = 0$ the system completely attenuates the input at that frequency, or if $H(\omega) = 1$ the signal passes unaltered and if $ |H(\omega)| = 10 $ then the system applies a linear **gain** of $10$ which corresponds to a dB scale of $20$ at that frequency.

Let's find the **magnitude** of the frequency response $H(\omega)$ :

$$
\begin{align}
H(\omega) &= 1 + 0.5 e^{-j \omega} + 0.25 e^{-j2\omega} \\
&= 1 + 0.5 (\cos(\omega)-j\sin(\omega) ) + 0.25 (\cos(2\omega)-j\sin(2\omega) ) \\
&= [ 1 + 0.5 \cos(\omega) + 0.25 \cos(2\omega)] -j [0.5 \sin(\omega) + 0.25 \sin(2\omega) ] \\
&= A(\omega) - j B(\omega) \\
|H(\omega)| &= \sqrt{ A^2(\omega) + B^2(\omega) } \\
|H(\omega)| &= \sqrt{ [ 1 + 0.5 \cos(\omega) + 0.25 \cos(2\omega)]^2 + [0.5 \sin(\omega) + 0.25 \sin(2\omega) ]^2 } \\
\end{align}
$$

with the help of a computer you can evaluate this frequency response magnitude at any frequency you want and compute the **gain** of that filter that it applies to any input frequency at that frequency. Below figure shows the *Frequency Response* magnitude of this system (evaluated and plotted using Matlab)

[image]

As you can see, the gain is about $1.8$ at frequencies close to zero radian per sample, and the gain is about unity at frequencies close to $0.5 \pi$ radians per sample. Most often but not always, this gain is defined in terms of a dB (deci Bell) scale (instead of a linear one) using the formula:

$$ \text{Gain_dB} = 20 \log_{10}( \text{Gain_linear}) = 20 \log_{10}( |H(\omega)|) $$

which is plotted in the figure below:

[image]

AS you can see, at the frequency about $0.5 \pi$ radians per sample, where the linear gain is about $1$, the corresponding deciBell gain is about $0$ dB.